# how to use cut command -f flag as reverse

Tags: bash, awk, sed, using, cut

This is a text file called **a.txt**

```
ok.google.com  
abc.google.com
```

I want to select every subdomain separately
`cat a.txt | cut -d "." -f1`  (it select *ok* **From left side**)
`cat a.txt | cut -d "." -f2`  (it select *google* **from left side**)

Is there any way, so I can get result from right side
cat a.txt | cut   (so it can select *com* **From right side**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be few ways to do this, one way which I could think of right now could be using `rev` + `cut` + `rev` solution. Which will reverse the input by `rev` command and then set field separator as `.` and print fields as per they are from left to right(but actually they are reversed because of the use of `rev`), then pass this output to `rev` again to get it in its actual order.

```
rev Input_file | cut -d'.' -f 1 | rev
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to print the last field:

```sh
awk -F. '{print $NF}' a.txt
```

`-F.` sets the record separator to "."

`$NF` is the last field

And you can give your file directly as an argument, so you can avoid the famous "[Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)"

For other fields, but counting from the last, you can use expressions as suggested in the comment by @sundeep or described in the users's guide under
[4.3 Nonconstant Field Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nonconstant-Fields). For example, to get the domain, before the TLD, you can substract 1 from the Number of Fields `NF` :

```sh
awk -F. '{ print $(NF-1) }' a.txt
```

Comment: Thank for this
it works but the problem is I can not select second last and third last with $3 $2 or $1 bcoz I don't know the exact subdomain level

Comment: @Shin can you add the exact output required for your given sample (probably add more samples if number of dots can vary). You can use `$(NF-1)` to select last but one field, `$(NF-2)` for last but two and so on.

Comment: it's not working sir showing output -1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do after getting the values then you could use bash for splitting your domain into an array of its components:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=. read -ra comps <<< "ok.google.com"

echo "${comps[-2]}"
```

```
# or for bash < 4.2
echo "${comps[${#comps[@]}-2]}"
```

```
google
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use sed with a quantifier for the grouped value repeated till the end of the string.

- `(` Start group

  - `\.[^[:space:].]+` Match 1 dot and 1+ occurrences of any char except a space or dot
- `){1}` Close the group followed by a quantifier
- `$` End of string

Example

```
sed -E 's/(\.[^[:space:].]+){1}$//' file
```

Output

```
ok.google
abc.google
```

If the quantifier is `{2}` the output will be

```
ok
abc
```

Comment: `{1}` can be removed safely

Comment: @anubhava I left it there to point out that it can be changed to `{2}` `{3}` etc.. to remove repetitions from the right side.